# Distance from hypotenuse

Tags: geometry

I have a right-angle triangle $ABC$ with angle $A=\alpha$ and $B=90$. $AB$ has length $a$, $BC$ has length $b=1$, and $AC$ has length $\sqrt (a^2+1)$.

Consider a line perpendicular to the hypotenuse $AC$ which intersects $AC$ at point $D$, and intersects one of the other two sides at $E$ (including the point $E=B$). What is the length of $DE$?

Comment: it will depend on the location of the point $D$. Note that $\triangle{ADE}$ is similar to $\triangle{ABC}$

Comment: do you mean a general formula for DE?

Comment: Yes, a general formula. But I’ve struggled with it because of the potential discontinuity at $E=B$. However, it seems intuitive that there should be a sinusoidal curve describing $DE$, with zeroes at $E=A$ and $E=C$ and a maximum at $E=B$. Am I wrong?

Comment: "Sinusoidal" is misleading: the formula is linear in $x=AD$ and is not difficult to find. But you cannot have a single simple expression for all the values of $x$, if that is what troubles you. In other words, what you need is simply the equation of polygonal chain $ABC$, if $AC$ is along the $x$ axis.

Comment: Yes, it’s the fact there is not a single expression that’s been bugging me. I end up with 2 different $tan^-1$ expressions that are both true at $E=B$. And yes, you’re right that ‘sinusoidal’ is therefore misleading. I’ll attemp to find out more about polygonal chains. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to express the length of segment DE.

In triangle, ABC, put B at the origin, for convenience but with some loss of generality, and we put the 90  deg angle at B.

Point D is somewhere on the hypotenuse and point E is the intersection along the axes. then $$m_1=\frac{-(C_x-A_x)}{C_y-A_y}$$ is the slope of a line that is perpendicular to the hypotenuse.

Point E is composed of two cases.

$E=\begin{cases}
if\,[D_{y}-m_{1}D_{x}>0]\qquad & (0,D_{y}-m_{1}D_{x})\\
else & \left((m_{1}D_{x}-D_{y})/m_{1},0\right)
\end{cases}$

and the distance from D to E is given by $$dist=\sqrt{ \left(D_x - E_x \right)^{2} +  \left(D_y - E_y \right)^{2}}$$